# What should happen to a SCD 2 table record if the record becomes inactive?

Tags: sql, etl, scd, scd2

Let's say we have a table that has these values:

```
id| name| country| start_dt| end_dt| is_current| current_dt
1001| John| CA| 2001-01-10| 2012-06-01| TRUE| 2012-06-01
```

Next day, the same record comes from upstream and the SCD2 record modifies to:

```
id| name| country| start_dt| end_dt| is_current| partition_dt
1001| John| CA| 2001-01-10| 2012-06-01| FALSE| 2012-06-02
1001| John| US| 2012-06-01| 2016-06-02| TRUE| 2012-06-02
```

But on the third day, this record stops coming from upstream table.

**In this case, what should happen in the SCD2 table?**

*Scenario 1:
The record remains as it is.*

```
id| name| country| start_dt| end_dt| is_current| partition_dt
1001| John| CA| 2001-01-10| 2012-06-01| FALSE| 2012-06-03
1001| John| US| 2012-06-01| 9999-12-31| TRUE| 2012-06-03
```

*Scenario 2:
The record becomes inactive in the SCD2 table*

```
id| name| country| start_dt| end_dt| is_current| partition_dt
1001| John| CA| 2001-01-10| 2012-06-01| FALSE| 2012-06-03
1001| John| US| 2012-06-01| 2012-06-03| FALSE| 2012-06-03
```

Answer (score 0):

You leave the last version as IS_CURRENT=TRUE.

The last-known-good version of an SCD row is sometimes used *instead of* the time-sensitive version.  So you can write

```
select d.Name, sum(f.someval) totalVal
from somefact f
join somedim d
  on f.dimid = d.id 
  and d.is_current = 'TRUE'
```

for joins to the dimension that treat it as a non-SCD.